# move MYSQL connection to include.h?

Tags: c

I want to move the MySQL stuff to include.h
so that I can include that into any cgi script
and then with ease use mysql queries.

how can it be done ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "include.h"

int main() {

while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) { 

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;

char *server = "localhost";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "";  
char *database = "db";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

if (mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {


}else{

}

printf("Content-type: text/html;\r\n");
printf("\r\n");

FCGI_Finish();
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post the content of your "include.h" and describe what error you come across?

Comment: @wyc, currently.. empty. nothing is in it.

Comment: i tried to paste the MySQL stuff into the include.h but i ended up with lots of errors while compiling

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c. Remember to put #ifndef etc. in the header file