# How do i convert the below Arduino Code to Embedded c code?

Tags: arduino

Can Anyone Please Convert the following Arduino Code to Embedded c code? I am very thankful to the one who converts this to an embedded c code. (this code is for Arduino lcd interfacing with Ultrasonic sensor)

```
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
      int inches = 0;
      int cm = 0;

      // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
      LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

      void setup() {
        // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
        lcd.begin(16, 2);
        // Print a message to the LCD.
        pinMode(7, INPUT);
      }

      void loop() {
        lcd.clear();
        cm = 0.01723 * readUltrasonicDistance(7);
        inches = (cm / 2.54);
        if (cm<40){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        // print the number of seconds since reset:
        lcd.print("Caution: ");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Objects Nearby");
        delay(1000);
        }
      }

      long readUltrasonicDistance(int pin)
      {
        pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);  // Clear the trigger
        digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(2);
        // Sets the pin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
        digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
        pinMode(pin, INPUT);
        // Reads the pin, and returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
        return pulseIn(pin, HIGH);
      }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please be aware that this site does not offer any code translation service. Have a look at the FAQ on how to ask good questions so that someone would be able to help you.

Comment: Arduino is already embedded C code - just with some handy libraries... Are you trying to find the source code for these Arduino standard functions? You already have them - `\arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino` look in the directory.

Comment: I Just Want to convert this code to atmega328p code

Comment: It already is code for the atmega328P.  You don't need to change anything.

Comment: If you want the machine code for atmega328p code, just compile it using Arduino IDE for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you can't because the dependencies of this code are `LiquidCrystal.h` (written in C++ and it contains dependencies like `Arduino.h` or `Wire.h`, libraries exclusive of Arduino software) and because methods like `pinMode(int,int)`,`digitalWrite(int,int)`,`delayMicroseconds(int)` comes from `Arduino.h`.
You can make your LiquidCrystal library rewriting it from the original.
Here some resources: [C header and source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c#7110046), [compile and upload](https://www.instructables.com/id/AVR-Programming-with-Arduino-AVRdude-and-AVR-gcc/), [setup](http://maxembedded.com/2015/06/setting-up-avr-gcc-toolchain-on-linux-and-mac-os-x/), [standard avr libs](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html).
I hope this can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but is bit painful. Convert the  class based function into c type functions. Remove dependant functions and replace the function by your own.
and use **int main(void)** instead of **void loop()**.