# C extern keyword correct use

Tags: arrays, c, extern

I'm writing a simple library to colorize the terminal's text, but maybe i'm doing it wrong.

colors.h:

```
extern enum col;
extern char* colors[8];
extern char* bold_colors[8];

void printColor(char* color, char* str);
```

colors.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <colors.h>

enum col {
    BLACK, RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, PURPLE, CYAN, WHITE, MAX_VALUE
};

char* colors[8] = {
    [BLACK] = "\033[0;30m",
    [RED] = "\033[0;31m",
    [GREEN] = "\033[0;32m",
    [YELLOW] = "\033[0;33m",
    [BLUE] = "\033[0;34m",
    [PURPLE] = "\033[0;35m",
    [CYAN] = "\033[0;36m",
    [WHITE] = "\033[0;37m"
};

char* bold_colors[8] = {
    [BLACK] = "\033[1;30m",
    [RED] = "\033[1;31m",
    [GREEN] = "\033[1;32m",
    [YELLOW] = "\033[1;33m",
    [BLUE] = "\033[1;34m",
    [PURPLE] = "\033[1;35m",
    [CYAN] = "\033[1;36m",
    [WHITE] = "\033[1;37m"
};

void printColor(char* color, char* str) {
    printf("\033[0;37m");
    printf(color);
    printf(str);
    printf("\033[0;37m");
}
```

main.c

```
#include "colors.h"

printColor(colors[GREEN], "text");
```

The error: `identifier "GREEN" is undefinedC/C++(20)`

it should share the colors arrays across the files (multiple) but returns an error.

Comment: The name GREEN is unknown in the translation unit with main. So the compiler issues an error.

Comment: im currently learning c, what i have to do? thanks.

Comment: You probably want to move your enum to a header file and include that in both colors.c and main.c

Comment: Does `extern enum col;` do anything?  I only use it for variables as it's the default for functions.

Comment: If the only difference between color and bold color is 0 vs 1 then I would eliminate the data duplication and just write a function that bolds a color.  Alternatively use an X macro to generate both from the the same data.

Comment: I would also be tempted to either only store color (30, 31... ) and use a wrapper function to expand it to the full thing, or generate the array from the unique data and let the pre-processor handle the duplication.

Comment: `#include <colors.h>` looks bad... Angle brackets with `#include` won't necessarily be looking for the header file in the current directory... Something about this gives off an odour...

Comment: `enum col` is not a data instance, it is a data type, as such has no _linkage_ `extern` or otherwise.  Its definition needs to be visible where used.  Your colour arrays should probably also be `extern const char* const` (constant pointer to constant data).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C share multiple enums among different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66454554/c-share-multiple-enums-among-different-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You probably want to move your enum to a header file and include that in both colors.c and main.c

–
Allan Wind

I agree with this.

Programming in C includes compilation and linkage.

At compilation stage, declarations in h-files have effect in c-files, but c-files don't affect each other. Your problem happens here. You fix it by placing all used declarations in your h-file.

At linkage stage, compiled c-files are linked together. Your `extern` declarations take effect here. However, they are needed in the compilation stage too, so it's correct to put them in h-files.

Comment: So i dont need to define in header and then declare in file.c ? if i declare enum, and arrays in header file i get duplicate warning i suppose.

Comment: You usually declare things in headers and use extern for variables (and define variables in .c).  The `enum  col { ... }` is a declaration.

Comment: @Zio_Pagnotta There's a difference between _declaration_ and _definition_ that you need to pay attention to. `extern char* colors[8];` is a declaration (reference to something which is allocated and "spelled out" elsewhere) and all declarations may be located in the header file, whereas `char* colors[8] = ...;` is a definition and should not be in the header file. Using global variables is bad practice though, but that's another story.

Comment: The whole deal with declarations and definitions is complicated. For variables it's relatively simple (`extern` = declaration only; no `extern` = declaration+definition, though even with such a simple rule, there are some exceptions). For `enum`, if you have `{}`, it's declaration+definition; if you don't, it's declaration only. Not sure if this helps. In any case, if your `GREEN` enumerator doesn't appear at all in the h-file, you don't need to apply judgment — non-existent thing is neither declared nor defined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you managed to get this to compile cleanly, because a forward declaration `extern enum col;` of an enum isn't valid C.

C17 6.7.2.3:

> **Constraints**
> ...
> A type specifier of the form
> `enum` *identifier*
> without an enumerator list shall only appear after the type it specifies is complete.

This is not the case in your current header file. So you need to move the enum declaration to that header file, or it won't be visible to other translation units. I recommend always using it together with `typedef`:

```
// colors.h
typedef enum {
    BLACK, RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, PURPLE, CYAN, WHITE, MAX_VALUE
} col;
```

---

As noted in comments, custom header files should always be included with `#include "colors.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we put definitions of data types, structs, and enumeration types in header files， like your enum col, you should put it into your header file. Then if you want use these data types or structs to define some data entities, you just need to include that header file.

As for the arrays like colors、 bold_colors, where the actual data is stored, should be put into the source file.

As we can see, you define the arrays colors、 bold_colors as global variables in color.c, if you want to use them just in color.c, other module should not see these global variables, then extern is not recommended. On the contrary, if you need a shared global variable(like you use it in main.c), you can use extern in color.c or other source file, then you can visit it in that source file. It works, but, we prefer a safer way: define a global variable in a source file, declare an interface in header file, and implement it in source file, and use this interface to get or set the global variable you defined in source file.