# Visual studio #include "file.c" needed in every file

Tags: c, visual-studio

I recently wanted to test my C project on visual studio (I used visual studio code) but for some reason my other file (file.c) do not recognize function from my main file (main.c). I need to manually add #include in both files. I can compile the code normally using cmd (gcc main.c). If you have any idea what cause this I would be happy to hear.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int randNumber = 10;

#include "file.c"

int main ()
{
  int a = 10;
  int b = 2;
  printf ("%i", multiplication (a, b));
  return 0;
}
```

file.c:

```
int multiplication (int a, int b)
{
  return a * b * randNumber;
}
```

This runs normally in vs code but not in visual studio. (I can also compile the code with cmd outside of visual studio with the command (gcc main.c)) The thing that doesn't work is the randNumber, it gets an error saying (identifier "randNumber" is undefined).

Comment: Never include .c files. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c. Also please don't post pictures of code, post code as text.

Comment: Also, what do you think that `static` in front of a function definition is good for...? Why do you use it?

Comment: I don't know I follow a tutorial.

Comment: @ErayZaxy you probably misunderstood something in the tutorial. If possible show us that tutorial.

Comment: I notice one of your images shows `#define true 1;` and `#define false 0;`. Putting a semi-colon on the end of those pre-processor directives is a _really_ bad idea.

Comment: @ErayZaxy Well it was a rhetorical question. The sole purpose of `static` functions is to block other parts of the program from calling those functions, so called _private encapsulation_.

Answer (score 1):

You should not include source files (`.c`) in other source files. `software_rendering.c` uses types defined in `win32_platform.c`. For example, the `Render_Buffer` structure.

You need to put the common types and definitions in a header file (`.h`) and include that. Keeping the  `Render_Buffer` example: move the `Render_Buffer` structure definition in a header file and include that header file in both source files.

See [Creating your own header file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c) for details.

As a side note: please do not post images of your code, instead [paste it as text and properly format it as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: So I would need to do that for every file and every structure? I didn't have to do that in VS code, that is wierd.

Comment: As pointed out by Lundin in the comments, OP should also not be declaring functions that are called from code in other .c files as `static`.

Comment: @ErayZaxy when you say that it worked in vs code, does it mean that the editor did not complain or that the code actually compiled?

Comment: I can compile the code normally using a cmd.

Comment: @ErayZaxy Show us a [MCVE] that works on VS Code and fails on Visual Studio.

Comment: @ErayZaxy no pictures of text. [edit] your question and show your code as properly formatted text. Read this: [ask]

Comment: You should also include the command you use to compile your program.

Comment: "The thing that doesn't work is the randNumber, it gets an error saying (identifier "randNumber" is undefined) " So it does not compile.

Comment: @ErayZaxy don't put code in comments but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66528912/edit) your question instead.

Comment: @Jabberwocky is it okay now?

Comment: I can't seem to format the code properly.

Comment: @ErayZaxy your code was ill formatted because there were no line endings, I formatted it for you, but you could have done this yourself,