# Cant open Header file in C on VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, header

I am currently writing a program dealing with sockets in the C programming langiage.
i was told to declare a header file. Now It would be great if I could actually look inside the header file. please help me in how I could possibly open a header file while programming in C on VScode.

haven't tried anything that helped yet

Comment: What **have** you tried to do? What happens when you simply select from menu File -> Open File? Is the problem that you cannot find the header file on your computer?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, and copy-paste (as text) the build errors you get. Also please show us your `tasks.json` used to build (if you use it).

Comment: You can open header files in the same way you open your C source file within VS Code. What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: A header is just a useful convention in C. So if you want to have a header suitable for your `foo.c` file: open a new file and name it `foo.h` right beside it. Nothing prevents you from naming them different tough. Just a way for other people to understand, what your code is supposed to do. Check out other answered questions, if your problem really is a misunderstanding of what a header file is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c.

Comment: This works in visual studio, might work for vs code: Right click on `#include <filename.h>` then select "Open document" option.  It might also say "Go to document"... or similar.